# how to grab text of google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, recaptcha

For a form i use google recaptcha to prevent spamming.
I looked into the dom and the code of the recaptcha is like below:

```
<div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
   <label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label">
     <span aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>
     I'm not a robot
   </label>
</div>
```

I tried to grab the text `I'm not a robot` with javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var captchaText = $('#recaptcha-anchor-label').text();
   alert(captchaText);
});
```

Unfortunately, the alert is empty. How can i grab the text?

Comment: Recapcha is rendered later. Document ready is too early

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your method when recaptcha script has loaded and injected it's content into DOM. To do that the easiest method would be to add a callback method to script that loads in the recaptcha.

```js
export function createScript(url: string, callback?: Function): void {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;

    if (callback) {
        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            callback();
        });
    }

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

const recaptchaUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
createScript(recaptchaUrl, () => {
            // Insert your desired code
});
```